# underscore character is not getting parsed in logstash grok pattern?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am using grok pattern to match "java_1204569_priority2" this line. I want to get digits as job id. But while parsing underscore character causing problem. Can anyone help in this.

Comment: How are you trying to parse it?

Comment: Please put your current solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why its so hard:

```
java_%{INT:jobid}_priority2
```